# Purpose of AWS SAM, [Configuration] attribute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

When publish AWS Serverless Application in Visual Studio, it prompts the following screen:

[image]

What is the use of [Configuration] under the [Build Settings] section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Build Configuration that is used by Visual Studio to compile the project.  If it finds a configuration named "Release" that's what it will default to, otherwise it will default to the configuration that's currently selected inside Visual Studio.

This appears in multiple deployment wizards for the AWS toolkit.  The only place I could find documentation on it was in the Elastic Beanstalk publishing guide but the same should apply for Lambda/Serverless publishing.

[Publishing Elastic Beanstalk (see #7)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/deployment-beanstalk-traditional.html#key-considerations-for-deployment-to-a-vpc)

Comment: Not sure if I can conclude that the Build Configuration is totally useless when publishing AWS Serverless Application. If anyone else has further insight, do comment. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe not entirely useless but probably rarely used by most people since if you're deploying you probably want a release build.  Release vs Debug does have an effect with how the source is compiled.  In release unused variables don't get compiled, code written under #debug directive is not included, and there are a few other optimizations that are done.  I guess you could potentially create a configuration specifically for Serverless if there would be some other optimizations that could be done during the build process like a custom command that would copy extra files or something like that.